# Android - Ripple effect over custom ImageView on GridView

Tags: android, android-gridview, rippledrawable

In my Android app I have a GridView which displays a set of images, each one in a custom subclass of ImageView (TickedImageView), which displays a tick when the image is selected.
What I want to achieve is to display a ripple when the image gets touched. I have tried setting background to

```
?android:attr/selectableItemBackground
```

with no luck, also adding a wrapper layout with this background, but nothing seems to work.

My code is as follows:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/photos_grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
    android:numColumns="@integer/photos_grid_num_columns"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/spinner_toolbar" />
```

The layout of each GridView item is the following:

```
<utils.TickedImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/thumb"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

And the ImageView subclass (TickedImageView) is the following:

```
package utils;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import app.R;

public class TickedImageView extends ImageView {

    private boolean selected;
    private Bitmap mTickBmp;
    private Paint mDarkerPaint;
    private View.OnClickListener onImageClickListener;
    private int x, y;

    public TickedImageView(Context context) {
       super(context);
       init();
    }

    public TickedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
       init();
    }

    private void init() {
       super.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               setSelected(!isSelected());

               if (onImageClickListener != null)
                  onImageClickListener.onClick(TickedImageView.this);
           }
        });

        mDarkerPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mDarkerPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mDarkerPaint.setColor(0x80142030);

        mTickBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_done_white_48px);
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
        invalidate();
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (selected) {
            canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), getMeasuredWidth(), mDarkerPaint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(mTickBmp, x, y, null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener listener) {
        onImageClickListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);

        x = (getMeasuredWidth() / 2) - (mTickBmp.getWidth() / 2);
        y = (getMeasuredWidth() / 2) - (mTickBmp.getHeight() / 2);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To add your ripple effect, add the following :

Step 1 : Create a shape (drawable/defaultBackground.xml)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
<corners android:radius="8dp" />
```

Obviously you can customize it to your needs. This will be our default background.

Step 2 : Create the ripple background (drawable/rippleBackground.xml)

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="@color/selectedRed">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/defaultBackground"/>
```

Once again, you can change the color to whatever you need.

Step 3 : Add the ripple to your view :

```
<utils.TickedImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/thumb"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/rippleBackground"
android:focusable="true"
android:clickable="true" />
```

Comment: Thank you, but by using this ripple appears, but it's almost invisible. I tried changing color to colorControlHighlight and the same